# What is the issue of boost::asio async_connect in my server?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/thread_pool.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include "http_server.hh"

using namespace boost::asio;
using ip::tcp;

std::string desired_IP_address = "172.16.0.2"; // For example purposes

class Session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Session> {
public:
    Session(ip::tcp::resolver& resolver,tcp::socket socket, tcp::socket client_socket) : socket_(std::move(socket)), resolver_(resolver), client_socket_(std::move(client_socket)) {}

    void start() { 
        do_read();
    }

private:
    void do_read() {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        socket_.async_read_some(
            boost::asio::buffer(data_),
            [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length) {
                if (!ec) {
                    std::string request(data_.data(), length);
                    path_ = extract_path(request);
                    resolver_.async_resolve(
                        ip::tcp::resolver::query("172.16.0.4", "5000"),
                        [this,self](const boost::system::error_code& ec,
                            ip::tcp::resolver::iterator it) {
                            if (ec) {
                                std::cout  << "Error resolving " << "localhost" << ": "
                                        << ec.message()<< std::endl;
                                return;
                            }

                            // For simplicity, we'll assume the first endpoint will always
                            // be available.
                            //std::cout << "localhost" << ": resolved to " << it->endpoint()
                            //        << std::endl;
                            do_connect(it->endpoint());
                        });
                    //handle_request_async(path);
                }
            });
    }

    void do_connect(const ip::tcp::endpoint& dest) {
        // Remember that the Asio library will make copies of parameters passed
        // by const reference, so it's ok to let the endpoint go out of scope
        // when this method returns.
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("172.16.0.4"), 5000);
        client_socket_.async_connect(a
            endpoint, [this, self](const boost::system::error_code& ec) {
                if (ec) {
                    std::cout << "Error connecting to " << "localhost"<< ": "
                               << ec.message()<< std::endl;
                    return;
                }

                //std::cout << "localhost" << ": connected to "
                //          << client_socket_.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
                do_send_http_get();
            });
    }

    void do_send_http_get() {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        // At minimum, the remote server needs to know the path being fetched
        // and the host serving that path. The latter is required because a
        // single server often hosts multiple domains.
        request_ = std::string("GET /") + " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + "example.com" + "\r\n\r\n";
        async_write(
            client_socket_, buffer(request_),
            [this,self](const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t size) {
                if (ec) {
                    std::cout << "Error sending GET " << ec<< std::endl;
                    return;
                }

                //std::cout << "localhost" << ": sent " << size << " bytes"<< std::endl;
                do_recv_http_get_header();
            });
    }

    void do_recv_http_get_header() {
        // Since HTTP/1.1 is a text based protocol, most of it is human readable
        // by design. Notice how the "double end of line" character sequence
        // ("\r\n\r\n") is used to delimit message sections.
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        async_read_until(
            client_socket_, response_, "\r\n\r\n",
            [this, self](const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t size) {
                if (ec) {
                    std::cout << "Error receiving GET header " << ec;
                    return;
                }

                //std::cout << "localhost:5000" << ": received " << size << ", streambuf "
                //          << response_.size();

                // The asio::streambuf class can use multiple buffers
                // internally, so we need to use a special iterator to copy out
                // the header.
                std::string header(
                    buffers_begin(response_.data()),
                    buffers_begin(response_.data()) + size);
                response_.consume(size);

                //std::cout << "----------" << std::endl << "localhost:5000"
                //          << ": header length " << header.size() << std::endl
                //          << header << std::endl;

                // First we'll check for the explicit "Content-Length" length
                // field. This provides the exact body length in bytes.
                size_t pos = header.find("Content-Length: ");
                if (pos != std::string::npos) {
                    size_t len = std::strtoul(
                        header.c_str() + pos + sizeof("Content-Length: ") - 1,
                        nullptr, 10);
                    do_receive_http_get_body(len - response_.size());
                    return;
                }

                // The other alternative is a chunked transfer. There is a quick
                // way to determine the remaining length in this case.
                pos = header.find("Transfer-Encoding: chunked");
                if (pos != std::string::npos) {
                    do_receive_http_get_chunked_body();
                    return;
                }

                std::cout << "Unknown body length";
            });
    }

    void do_receive_http_get_body(size_t len) {
        // For "Content-Length" we know exactly how many bytes are left to
        // receive.
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        async_read(
            client_socket_, response_, transfer_exactly(len),
            [this,self] (const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t size) {
               handle_http_get_body(ec, size);
            });
    }

    void do_receive_http_get_chunked_body() {
        // For chunked transfers the final body chunk will be terminated by
        // another "double end of line" delimiter.
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        async_read_until(
            client_socket_, response_, "\r\n\r\n",
            [this,self] (const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t size) {
                handle_http_get_body(ec, size);
            });
    }

    void handle_http_get_body(const boost::system::error_code& ec,
                              std::size_t size) {
        if (ec) {
            std::cout << "Error receiving GET body " << ec;
            return;
        }

        //std::cout << "localhost:5000" << ": received " << size << ", streambuf "
        //          << response_.size();

        // We can finally consume the body and print it out if desired.
        const auto& data = response_.data();
        std::string response_body(buffers_begin(data), buffers_end(data));
        response_.consume(size);

        //std::cout << "----------" << std::endl << "localhost:5000" << ": body length "
        //          << response_body.size() << std::endl;
        //std::cout << response_body << std::endl;
        handle_request_async();
    }


    void handle_request_async() {
        auto self(shared_from_this());

        async_response([this,self](const std::string& response) {
            // std::cout << "path " <<  path_ << std::endl;
            // std::cout << response << std::endl;
            async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(response),
                [this,self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/) {
                    if (!ec) {
                        //std::cout << "response" << std::endl;
                        boost::system::error_code ignored_ec;
                        socket_.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ignored_ec);
                    }
                });
        });
    }

    void async_response(std::function<void(const std::string&)> callback) {
        // Assuming handle_request returns HTTP_Response asynchronously
        HTTP_Response* htmlResponse = handle_request(path_);
        //std::cout << "path: " << path << std::endl;
        std::string response = htmlResponse->body;
        //std::cout << "content: " << response << std::endl;
        callback(response);
        
        delete htmlResponse;
    }

    // Function to extract path from the HTTP request
    std::string extract_path(const std::string& request) {
        // Logic to extract path from the request string
        // Example logic: extracting the path after the GET method
        std::string path;
        //std::cout << request << std::endl;
        // Implement your path extraction logic here

        // Find the end of the request line (the first line of the HTTP request)
        std::size_t requestLineEnd = request.find("\r\n");
        if (requestLineEnd != std::string::npos) {
            std::string requestLine = request.substr(0, requestLineEnd);

            // Split the request line into parts (method, path, protocol)
            std::vector<std::string> parts;
            boost::split(parts, requestLine, boost::is_any_of(" "));

            // The second part typically contains the path (e.g., "GET /path HTTP/1.1")
            if (parts.size() >= 2) {
                path = parts[1]; // Extract the path from the request line
            }
        }

        return path;
    }

    tcp::socket socket_;
    tcp::socket client_socket_;
    std::array<char, 8192> data_;
    std::string path_;

    std::string request_;
    boost::asio::streambuf response_;
    ip::tcp::resolver& resolver_;

};

class Server {
public:
    Server(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, short port)
        : acceptor_(io_context, tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::make_address(desired_IP_address), port)),
          //acceptor_(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)),
          socket_(io_context), resolver_(io_context), client_socket_(io_context)
    {
        do_accept();
    }

private:
    void do_accept() {
        acceptor_.async_accept(
            socket_,
            [this] (boost::system::error_code ec) {
                if (!ec) {
                    std::make_shared<Session>(resolver_, std::move(socket_), std::move(client_socket_))->start();
                }
                do_accept();
            });
    }

    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
    tcp::socket socket_;
    tcp::socket client_socket_;
    ip::tcp::resolver resolver_;
};

int main() {
    try {
        boost::asio::io_context io_context;
        Server server(io_context, 8080);
        boost::asio::thread_pool pool(40);
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 40; ++i)
            boost::asio::post(pool, [&io_context]() { io_context.run(); });

        pool.join();
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting error **"Error connecting to localhost: Cannot assign requested address"**
This is error at the async_connect call.
I am getting this error when the server is pinned to one core and the cpu_utilization of the core is 100%. There is periodic drop of throughput also observed.

**NOTE: This server is present in a different linux network namespace than the server to which it is trying to connect**

One more thing **This issue is happening only when there is inter-network namespace communication and doesn't happen when running the servers in the same linux network namespace or on localhost.**

Answer (score 0):

`io_context.run()` is blocking.

You are posting it 40 times to as many service threads, ironically making sure that ZERO threads are able to make any further progress.

It appears you are mistaking `asio::threadpool` for something like `boost::thread_group`. In constrast `asio::threadpool` already **is-a** [execution_context](https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/execution_context.html) and by definition all threads attach to the pool already `run` the service.

All in all, the simpler main looks like:

```
int main() try {
    asio::thread_pool pool;
    Server            server(pool.get_executor(), 8080);
    pool.join();
} catch (std::exception const& e) {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

I'm afraid the rest of the code has some red flags:

- async_response takes `std::function` which risks defeating Asio executors
- you have loads of threads. This is an antipattern in itself, but especially since none of the operations employ a strand
- you are running bespoke HTTP message "parsing". Prefer to use a library for that (e.g. Boost Beast). Specifically, it looks your code  will not deal with HTTP 1.1 features
- every accept moves from the same `client_socket_`. That's... useless at best
- there really isn't any reason to "assume the first endpoint is valid". Just use `asio::async_connect`

When push comes to shove, it's unclear to me whether you are simply implementing a relaying HTTP proxy (it looks a lot like it) or ... a general HTTP server. Right now it looks a lot like you're receiving a request which you would relay to upstream. However, with the code as given the response from the upstream server... is treated as a request?!? which is then fed into `handle_request`. It looks like that piece of code is misplaced.

Regardless, here is the result of me pooring over this code for a long time and coming up with a ton of improvements that you will probably be able to use. I replaced the missing header `http_server.hh` with

```
using Request  = http::request<http::string_body>;
using Response = http::response<http::string_body>;

http::message_generator handle_request(fs::path path) {
    std::cout << "path " << path << std::endl;

    path = fs::current_path() / path; // emulate virtual root, NOTE: not secure!

    if (exists(path) && fs::is_regular_file(path)) {
        http::response<http::file_body> res(http::status::ok, 11);

        error_code ec;
        res.body().open(path.c_str(), boost::beast::file_mode::scan, ec);
        std::cout << res.base() << std::endl;
        return res;
    } else {
        http::response<http::string_body> res(http::status::ok, 11);
        res.body() = "TODO:" + path.native();
        std::cout << res << std::endl;
        return res;
    }
}
```

This will respond to paths that correspond to existing files in the server's working directory by sending that file, otherwise a body of `TODO:` with the request path.

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88a70a0452a199dc)**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace http = boost::beast::http;
namespace fs   = std::filesystem;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;

// #include "http_server.hh"
using Request  = http::request<http::string_body>;
using Response = http::response<http::string_body>;

http::message_generator handle_request(fs::path path) {
    std::cout << "path " << path << std::endl;

    path = fs::current_path() / path; // emulate virtual root, NOTE: not secure!

    if (exists(path) && fs::is_regular_file(path)) {
        http::response<http::file_body> res(http::status::ok, 11);

        error_code ec;
        res.body().open(path.c_str(), boost::beast::file_mode::scan, ec);
        std::cout << res.base() << std::endl;
        return res;
    } else {
        http::response<http::string_body> res(http::status::ok, 11);
        res.body() = "TODO:" + path.native();
        std::cout << res << std::endl;
        return res;
    }
}

struct Session : std::enable_shared_from_this<Session> {
    Session(tcp::socket socket)
        : downstream_{std::move(socket)}
        , upstream_{downstream_.get_executor()}
        , resolver_{downstream_.get_executor()} {}

    ~Session() { std::cerr << "Session closed" << std::endl; }

    void start() {
        std::cerr << "Accepted from " << downstream_.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
        do_read();
    }

  private:
    void do_read() {
        http::async_read(
            downstream_, downbuf_, request_,
            [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t /*length*/) {
                std::cout << "Received " << ec.message() << ": " << request_.base() << std::endl;
                if (ec)
                    return;
                path_     = request_.target();
                auto host = request_.at(http::field::host);
                auto port = "http"; // TODO parse port from host?

                resolver_.async_resolve(host, port, [this, self](error_code ec, auto eps) {
                    std::cout << "Resolved upstream: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                    if (ec)
                        return;

                    for (auto&& ep : eps)
                        std::cout << " - candidate: " << ep.endpoint() << std::endl;

                    asio::async_connect(upstream_, eps, [this, self](error_code ec, tcp::endpoint) {
                        std::cout << "Connect upstream: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                        if (!ec) {
                            std::cout << "upstream: " << upstream_.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
                            do_relay();
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
    }

    void do_relay() {
#if true
        // keep the request as received from downstream_
#else
        // At minimum, server needs the path & host header
        request_ = Request{http::verb::get, "/", 11};
        request_.set(http::field::host, "example.com");
#endif

        async_write(upstream_, request_, [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t size) {
            std::cout << "Relayed upstream: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            if (!ec) {
                std::cout << "sent to upstream: " << size << " bytes" << std::endl;
                do_recv_response();
            }
        });
    }

    void do_recv_response() {
        response_.clear();
        http::async_read(
            upstream_, upbuf_, response_, [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t /*size*/) {
                if (ec) {
                    std::cout << "Error receiving GET header " << ec.message();
                    return;
                }

                std::cout << "-- Response headers -- " << response_.base() << std::endl;

                if (response_.has_content_length()) {
                    std::cout << "-- Content-Length header = " << response_.at(http::field::content_length)
                              << std::endl;
                }

                if (response_.chunked())
                    std::cout << "-- Received using chunked encoding" << std::endl;

                std::cout << "-- Actual Body Length: " << response_.body().length() << std::endl;
                std::cout << "-- Body:               " << response_.body() << std::endl;

                // this looks REALY out of place
                boost::beast::async_write( //
                    downstream_, handle_request(path_),
                    [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t /*length*/) {
                        if (!ec) {
                            // std::cout << "response" << std::endl;
                            error_code ignored_ec;
                            downstream_.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ignored_ec);
                        }
                    });
            });
    }

    tcp::socket     downstream_;
    asio::streambuf downbuf_;
    tcp::socket     upstream_;
    asio::streambuf upbuf_;

    Request         request_;
    Response        response_;
    std::string     path_;

    tcp::resolver   resolver_;
};

struct Server {
    Server(asio::any_io_executor ex, uint16_t port, std::string bind_address = "172.16.0.2")
        : acceptor_(ex, tcp::endpoint(asio::ip::make_address(bind_address), port)) {
        do_accept();
    }

  private:
    void do_accept() {
        acceptor_.async_accept(make_strand(acceptor_.get_executor()), [this](error_code ec, tcp::socket s) {
            if (!ec)
                std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(s))->start();

            do_accept();
        });
    }

    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main() try {
    asio::thread_pool pool;
    Server            server(pool.get_executor(), 8080, "0.0.0.0");
    pool.join();
} catch (std::exception const& e) {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

With a local interactive demo:

[image]

Comment: Do you think the above improvements can solve my issue of throughput drop in my servers when in different linux namespaces ?

Comment: Possibly. First check whether it does what you need. Some of the choices will make it slower (e.g. the strand makes it correct, but typically not faster. Avoiding strands might be what you want). Also, it seems like "Cannot assign requested address" would simply indicate that you misconfigured `bind_address` (your `desired_IP_address`) for the container. It could be that your server causes 100% CPU due to error-handling in a tight loop? Of course fixing that will solve the degraded performance during that time. Also, consider just binding to "0.0.0.0" if you can, this avoids any mismatch

Comment: But the issue is, the throughput drop is only happening when communication is between 2 different linux namespaces, no on localhost and not when all servers are in the same network namespace. So it doesn't seem like implementation issue.
The issue started in cpprestsdk(which uses boost asio internally), so tried to move to boost asio, to see if the same issue is present. The same thing is happening boost asio too. Profiling using perf on cpprestsdk server too also shows issue with connect. Binding shouldn't be an issue, since server works and in between I get some errors like this.

Comment: I think that was all repeated informatiion. Maybe you can write a docker-compose script that is able to reproduce the issue. If reproduced it's either ging to be misconfiguration of a docker issue, I suppose

Comment: I have now boiled it down to linux network namespace, not even using any third party containerization like Docker. Still getting the same issue. Can't be Docker misconfiguration.

Comment: If you can show/share it we might help. It might make sense as a separate question. If you can demonstrate without own code (like using netcat) it could be better suited for SuperUser or Unix stackexchange

Comment: But it seems the issue is in async_connect of the boost library. I used your code in my scenario and still I'm getting throughput drop issue. 
There seems to issue with the connect function of boost in case of inter-namespace communication. Can pinning the server to one core give periodic drop in throughput ? (Starts with normal throughput, drops low and then again reaches normal level, and this continues)

Comment: I dunno. Can it? We can investigate IFF we can reproduce it